# Правильное место хранение загруженных изображений Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, path

Относительно архитектуры Spring где корректно хранить изображения загруженные через форму? Изображения это фотографии товаров и соответственно к ним нужно иметь доступ. Как правильно указать место хранения?

Если указать так  *String path = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("").getPath();* то путь получится в target, а значит папка будет удалена если запустить maven clean.

Или нужно указывать прямо *C:\...*, но как тогда быть при переносе с локального сервера на удаленный.

Answer (score -3):

Если речь идет о изображениях загружаемых через форму, то их нужно сохранять в **базе данных**.

Если это картинки, которые нужно показывать всякий раз когда пользователь открывает какую то часть страницы или страницу полностью, то создайте для всех изображений папку **img** путь будет например такой: WEB-INF/resources/img, и держите их там.

Comment: Спасибо, но разве нужно хранить в базе сами файлы,а не ссылку на них (в плане названия и пути к ним)?
И можно ли динамически получить путь  к "WEB-INF/resources/img"?

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, то можно. Например в базе будут записи: [...][imgId = '123d'][...]; [...][ingId = '114b'][...]. Вы получаете модель далее приписываете соответствующий id картинки в src. Но важный момент, что эти картинки должны все хранится в resource/img, причем все вместе и сразу.

Comment: но как получить получить путь к "WEB-INF/resources/img"?

Comment: <mvc:resources mapping="resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources/"/>
вот так

Comment: картинки туда перемещаться во время работы программы не будут - я уже пробовала.

Comment: чтобы какая то картинка загрузилась должен быть соответствующий запрос. <img src="URL" alt="альтернативный текст" /> путь там где url

Comment: Вы уж меня извините, но основы HTML я знаю. Проблема в том что картинка в архив с приложением перемещаться во время работы не будет. Собственно поэтому у меня и возникла проблема.

Comment: Что значит в архив с приложением?

Comment: имею в виду war

Comment: А что мешает хранить все картинки в *.war?

Comment: мне нужно добавлять их во время работы - фотографии товаров загружаются в форме. а в war они не сохраняются

Comment: *.war это отдельный instance твоего приложения, такой же как и локально. У него есть все теже *.property что и у тебя, есть так же коннект к БД. соответственно когда картинка загружается через форму, она обрабатывается и сохраняется в БД, настройки конекта к БД, прописуются в соотв. файле. И когда картинка сохранена, ты можешь получить ее в instance *.war ну тоесть она не будет хранится в *.war а только передастся по сети.

Comment: Вы предлагаете хранить картинку как поле в БД? blob?

Comment: ага..........................